# Скрипт проверки формы , перед отправкой

Tags: javascript, jquery

скрипт, проверяет инпуты перед отправкой формы, и придает им класс `error`, подскажите как отредактировать чтобы этот класс добавлялся еще в блок `.error-text`

```js
$("button.send").on("click", function(s) {
  s.preventDefault();
  var e = $(this).closest("form"),
    n = !0;
  return $("form").find("input.required").removeClass("error"), e.find("input.required, textarea.required").each(function() {
    return "" === $(this).val() ? ($(this).addClass("error"), $(this).focus(), n = !1, !1) : void 0
  }), n && ($("form").find("input.required, textarea.required").parent().removeClass("error"), e.submit()), !1
});
```

```css
.main-input {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  &.error {
    border-color: red;
  }
}

.error-text {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  &.error {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="c-ordering-form">
  <input class="main-input required" type="text" placeholder="ФИО" required="required" />
  <input class="main-input required" type="email" placeholder="E-mail" required="required" />
  <input class="main-input required" type="tel" placeholder="Телефон" required="required" />
  <button class="send">отправить</button>
  <div class="error-text">Ошибка</div>
</form>
```

[Оригинал кода](https://codepen.io/serhiybilyk/pen/oyGVpO)

Answer (score 0):

```js
  $('.send').on('click',function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var $inputArr = $('.c-ordering-form input');
   var inputLength = $inputArr.length;
   var count = 0;
   $.each($inputArr,function(i,v){
    if ($(v).val() == ''){
     $('.error-text, .c-ordering-form').addClass('error');
     $(v).addClass('error');
    } else {
     count += 1
     $(v).removeClass('error');
     count == inputLength ? $('.c-ordering-form , .error-text').removeClass('error') : ''   
    }
   })
  })
```

```css
.main-input {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
 }
 .main-input.error {
  border-color: red;
 }

 .error-text {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
 }
 .error {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="c-ordering-form">
  <input class="main-input required" type="text" placeholder="ФИО" required="required" />
  <input class="main-input required" type="email" placeholder="E-mail" required="required" />
  <input class="main-input required" type="tel" placeholder="Телефон" required="required" />
  <button class="send">отправить</button>
  <div class="error-text">Ошибка</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Нужно `error` добавить до `.error-text`

Comment: @SerhiyBilik а разница в чём, поменяйте местами названия)))

Comment: ваш пример добавляет класс `error-text` и `error` к инпутам, а мне нужно добавить класс `error`  до инпута и к блоку с классом `error-text`

Comment: @SerhiyBilik к c-ordering-form чтоли? Правильно формулируйте вопрос изначально. Вы скидываете код и непонятно что куда и как вам надо, класов то этих изначально нет.

Comment: Класс `error` не должен быть изначально! потому что он добавляется только если инпут пустой!
а блок с классом `error-text` есть! посмотрите внимательней, находится под кнопкой.
и этому блоку нужно добавить класс `error`, если при отправке формы какой-то инпут пустой

Comment: @SerhiyBilik смотрите. изначально описывайте более подробно что надо